Sent bitcoin to my new bitcoin core wallet, but not showing up
I am SUPER newbie to this stuff, please help and be patient.  I needed a place to send a large bitcoin transaction, and decided to impulsively download bitcoin core to receive it on my desktop.  There are over 6 confirmations, but its not showing up in my bitcoin core wallet.  Is this because it hasn't synced the multi-year transactions yet?  will it show up when it does sync? i'm so darn confused and kinda worried....

Bitcoin Core is processing the entire blockchain to synchronize with the network. Given that you have verified that your transaction was included in the blockchain and assuming that your address has been credited by the transaction output, your transaction will show up when your Bitcoin Core node has caught up to the block that confirmed it. Depending on the hardware and internet connection of your node, this may take a few hours to some days. If you received a sizeable amount to your Bitcoin Core wallet, please be sure to backup your wallet.
